# Connection refused for a single IP address - CentOS 7/Apache/Laravel

Tags: php, linux, apache, laravel, centos

[Connection refused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkJQr.jpg)

I have a website that has been developed in Laravel 5 and is running on CentOS 7/Apache. For one, and only one, of my clients, visiting the site produces the above "**Connection refused**" error message. The odd thing is that this is a public facing website and no other user seems to be able to recreate this issue -- all other users visit the site with no issues. I have had numerous people test and only for this one specific location/IP does this occur.

As far as I know, there is no intentional configuration on the server that would be blocking one specific IP. I have also asked my hosting provider if they are somehow blocking that one IP and they have said they are not and that it would be an issue with my VPS/website or with the client's network.

My question is, what can I check on my VPS/website to verify this is not being caused by something on our server? The client claims that everything should be working on their network and they are asking me to troubleshoot on our side. I am not a networking expert so I'm not even sure where to look. Any help would be appreciated. As I said, the site is up and working for every other user that has tested so I'm not sure why a single location would receive "Connection refused".

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if I need to post some sort of configuration information from the server.

Thanks.

Comment: Ask the client to do standard network debugging. `ping` and `traceroute` to determine whether they can reach your server. But in any case, this network admin type question is not appropriate for Stackoverflow which is for programming related questions. You may want to try over at [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Check for Apache logs for that Ip, but it is probably a client issue, like some sort of proxy/firewall blocking the request.

Links to similar issue:

https://forums.bluecoat.com/forum/security-policy-enforcement-center/proxysg/4351-network-error-tcp_error

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b8a4cdec-112a-43fe-a4d4-dc851ac10434/fix-network-error-tcperror-a-communication-error-occurred-connection-refused?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm reading through those links now. I did check the Apache logs and I don't see any visits from those IPs recently. There are some from several days ago but according to the client, this issue just started yesterday. I'm thinking that since I don't even have a log of them attempting to connect, that the "Connection refused" must be occurring prior to it getting to Apache.